# Ошибка Компиляции Java not a statemen

Tags: java, компиляция

```
GamePacketHandler gph = new GamePacketHandler();

InetAddress serverAddr = Config.GAMESERVER_HOSTNAME.equalsIgnoreCase("*") ? null : InetAddress.getByName(Config.GAMESERVER_HOSTNAME);

this._selectorThreads = new SelectorThread[Config.PORTS_GAME.length];
for (int i = 0; i < Config.PORTS_GAME.length; i++)
{
  this._selectorThreads[i] = new SelectorThread(Config.SELECTOR_CONFIG, gph, gph, gph, null);
  try
  {
    InetAddress[] addrs = InetAddress.getAllByName(Config.EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME);
    for (InetAddress addr : addrs)
    {
      int[] arrayOfInt = VALUES;int m = arrayOfInt.length;
      for (int n = 0; n < m; n++)
      {
        Integer a = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInt[n]);
        if (a.intValue() == Arrays.hashCode(addr.getAddress())) {
          break label783;
        }
      }
    }
    this._selectorThreads[i]; SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    label783:
    this._selectorThreads[i]; SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L;
  }
  this._selectorThreads[i].openServerSocket(serverAddr, Config.PORTS_GAME[i]);
  this._selectorThreads[i].start();
}
```

При компиляции - javac -classpath server.jar -Xlint:unchecked GameServer.java

Ошибка1) - GameServer.java:272: error: not a statement

```
    this._selectorThreads[i]; SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L;
```

Ошибка2) - GameServer.java:277: error: not a statement

```
    this._selectorThreads[i]; SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L;
```

Comment: `this._selectorThreads[i];` - это не является оператором

Comment: а можно по подробнее где именно мне нужно изменить чтобы все скомипилровалось, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой

Comment: ну я же не провидец, откуда мне знать, что Вы хотите. Судя по коду надо либо что-то присвоить этому элементу массива, либо вызвать у объекта, находящегося в массиве, какой-то метод.

Comment: Объясню на обычном языке, т.к. сам в Java (0) если InetAdress соответсвует в конфиге, то применить эту функцию макс конект =10 , если же инет адрес несоотвествует в конфиге то применить break label783, в данный момент мне нужно изменить макс коннектион на 2000, также и в бреке на 2000

Comment: `то применить эту функцию макс конект =10 ` - вот этой функции я не вижу, а вижу попытку присвоить статической переменной класса значения 10. И от меток избавьтесь.

Comment: java:272: error: not a statement возникает, когда от вас ждут выражения - то есть ссылки на какую-то переменную, а вы впихиваете значение.
Отсюда рекомменадация - каждую логическую строку пишите на отдельной строке. Логическая строка - то что обособляется оператором
`;`

Comment: Мне больше всего не нравится вот это
`SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L;`
L - Это модификатор лонга. Может быть ему требуется там тип инт, или вообще какой-то enum.

Comment: Просто если бы вы обособляли логические строки, мы бы точно знали, ошибка в массиве или в максимальном подключении.

Comment: ошибка в массиве

Comment: если скинуть SelectorThread.MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10L; на след строку то ошибка возникает на this._selectorThreads[i];

Comment: Может нужно скинуть полный текст? файла .java ???

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Может нужно полный код скинуть? от А до Я чтобы было наглядно видно, я просто не разбираюсь Java языке, но очень хочу научится

Comment: Ну закиньте на гитхаб, сейчас у меня времени нет, но вечером я допускаю что могу глянуть.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin у меня это не проект ( к сожалению нету исходного кода) но за помощь готов отблагодарить заранее спс http://rgho.st/64byy6XKs